# laravel ajax Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: ajax, laravel

please help me solve this error
i tried too much but it still returns an error i don't know why please help
it returns Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list at line that contains

```
<td>' + item.name + '</td>\
```

here is my code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    fetchpost();
    function fetchpost() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/fetchpost",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                // console.log(response);
                $('tbody').html("");
                $.each(response.posts, function (key, item) {
                    $('tbody').append('<tr>\
                        <td>' + item.id + '</td>\
                        <td>' + item.name + '</td>\
                        <td><a href="'posts/+item.id'">show</a></td>\
                        <td><button type="button" value="' + item.id + '" class="btn btn-primary editbtn btn-sm">Edit</button></td>\
                        <td><button type="button" value="' + item.id + '" class="btn btn-danger deletebtn btn-sm">Delete</button></td>\
                    \</tr>');
                });
            }
        });
    }
})
```

Comment: `<td><a href="'posts/+item.id'">show</a></td>` is missing a "+". It should be `<td><a href="'posts/' + item.id + '">show</a></td>`

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to concat the string `<td><a href=posts/"'+item.id+'">show</a></td>\`

Anyway try with this code:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    fetchpost();
    function fetchpost() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/fetchpost",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                // console.log(response);
                $('tbody').html("");
                $.each(response.posts, function (key, item) {
                    $('tbody').append('<tr>\
                        <td>' + item.id + '</td>\
                        <td>' + item.name + '</td>\
                        <td><a href=posts/"'+item.id+'">show</a></td>\
                        <td><button type="button" value="' + item.id + '" class="btn btn-primary editbtn btn-sm">Edit</button></td>\
                        <td><button type="button" value="' + item.id + '" class="btn btn-danger deletebtn btn-sm">Delete</button></td>\
                    \</tr>');
                });
            }
        });
    }
})
```